# How can I get all pairs of values from an association with elements key->list

Tags: list-manipulation, functional-style, associations

I have an association of the form

```
ds=<|key1 -> list1, key2 -> list2,... ,keyn -> listn|>
```

I would like a simple way to map a function to all pairs `{a, b}`, where `a` is a key and `b` is element of the list associated with key `a`.  I have found several brute-force methods but is seems that there should be something akin to

```
f /@ ds
```

This only feeds `f` with the lists one by one.

I can do it this way:

```
g[a_, b_] := h[a, #] & /@ b

Flatten@KeyValueMap[g, ds]
```

Is there a more compact way?

Comment: Please include your brute force methods! Especially if they do what you want! - that way, if we come up with what we think is a better solution, we can compare and make sure our results are correct. In addition, it's not clear what the output should be. Do you replace the `Value` with the output of the function? Do you replace the `Key`? Is the result just supposed to be a `List` of the computed values?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`KeyValueMap`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/KeyValueMap.html):

```
ds = <|key1 -> list1, key2 -> list2, keyn -> listn|>;

KeyValueMap[f] @ ds
```

$\ $`{f[key1, list1], f[key2, list2], f[keyn, listn]}`

```
ds = <|key1 -> {x1, y1}, key2 -> {x2, y2}, keyn -> {x3, y3}|>;

KeyValueMap[f[#1, #2[[1]]] &, ds]
```

$\ $`{f[key1, x1], f[key2, x2], f[keyn, x3]}`

Comment: This is close, what I need is f[key1,x1],f[key1,y1],f[key2,x2],f[key2,y2], etc.

Comment: @JJM in that case how about `Flatten@KeyValueMap[Thread[f[##]] &, ds]` or `Flatten@KeyValueMap[f /* Thread, ds]`

Comment: @JJM "what I need is" - you really should edit your question to include that.

Comment: @Mike Honeychurch Yes, this is what I was looking for.  Thanks to you and Karsten 7